# Use a raster Stack in foreach loop with doParallel in R

Tags: r, foreach, raster

I want to perform a series of calculations on each layer in a large raster stack in R, and save the results for each layer as a separate raster for later use. I am trying to speed up the process using foreach and doParallel.  Here is the basic code, with a trivial calculation (*3) for each layer in the stack:

```
library(raster)
library(doParallel)

RasterStack<- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
RasterStack<-addLayer(RasterStack,RasterStack)

cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

RasterStack<- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
RasterStack<-addLayer(RasterStack,RasterStack)

foreach(rasname=iter(names(RasterStack)),packages="raster") %dopar%{
  ras<-RasterStack[[rasname]]*3
  save(ras,file=paste0(rasname,"_new.Rras"))
}
```

It mostly works, but the first N layers are not processed, where N is the number of nodes (e.g. 2 in above). I get the following error:   Error in { : task 1 failed - "this S4 class is not subsettable".  The error mostly only happens after all other layers have been processed correctly (i.e. its only the first N layers that don't work, and this mostly doesn't stop the other layers being processed -though occasionally it does). All layers get processed correctly if run sequentially with %do%.
Can anyone explain this behavior, or offer a solution?
Thanks

Comment: You also could consider to use [`spatial.tools`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatial.tools/index.html).

Comment: Please specify which packages you're using. Is the code you provided reproducible?

Comment: I'm using raster and doParallel. I've edited the code so that is now reproducible (using the logo example from ?stack).

Comment: `save(ras, file=paste0(rasname,"_new.Rras"))` is not a safe way of storing raster data for more than 24 hrs, as `ras` may point to a temporary file. You need to use `writeRaster` (or similar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that there is just the `.` in front of `packages` missing. This works for me:

```
foreach(rasname = iter(names(RasterStack)), .packages = "raster") %dopar% {
  ras <- RasterStack[[rasname]] * 3
  save(ras, file = paste0(rasname, "_new.Rras"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your results put into a new stack instead of separate files:

```
# libraries
library(raster)
library(doParallel)

# fake data
RasterStack1 <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
RasterStack1 <- addLayer(RasterStack1, RasterStack1)
plot(RasterStack1)

# make cluster
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# parallel loop
RasterStack2 <- foreach(rasname=iter(names(RasterStack1)), 
                    .packages="raster") %dopar% {
RasterStack1[[rasname]]*3
}

# make result a stack
RasterStack2 <- stack(RasterStack2)
plot(RasterStack2)

# stop cluster
stopCluster(cl)
```